# Block-Based Animation does not Work: Animations and Completion Blocks are Executed Immediately (Without Duration)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I tried to animate some features of the UIView, anyway, I simplified everything to these code lines in "ViewController.m":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 5.0 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"animations");}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"completion");}];
    }
```

Both blocks outputs immediately after loading despite the fact that animation should last five seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use block animations in `viewDidLoad` because the UIView you want to animate doesn't have superview at the present moment. Move the code to the `viewDidAppear` method.